# foreach item in class list

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach

I have a class like so:

```
public class OverDueClass
{
     public int CustomerID { get; set; }
     public int Question_ID { get; set; }
     public string Department { get; set; }
     public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I am populating this class and passing it to another method:

```
while (dataReader.Read())
{
      OverDueClass overDueItem = new OverDueClass();

      overDueItem.CustomerID = (int)dataReader[0];
      overDueItem.Question_ID = (int)dataReader[1];
      overDueItem.Department = dataReader[2].ToString();
      overDueItem.DueDate = (DateTime)dataReader[3];

      OverDueCell.Add(overDueItem);
}  

sendEmail("fake@email.com", OverDueCell);
```

Now in the other method, I can see the data is being passed.

Now I am trying to run a `foreach` to do something with the data and I tried the following:

```
foreach(string item in overDue)
{

}
```

But I get this error:

> Cannot covert type to string.

Comment: `overDue` I'm assuming is a single `OverDueClass`, its not an array or collection, so you can't `foreach` over it. Are you trying to iterate through all the properties in the class?

Comment: @RonBeyer...Because he sent `OverDueCell` as a parameter to `sendEmail` method, I think `overDue` would be `OverDueCell`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `overDue` is the `OverDueCell` then change `string` to `OverDueClass` in `foreach` like this:

```
foreach(OverDueClass item in overDue)
{

}
```

Or use [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword:

```
foreach(var item in overDue)
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are attempting to iterate thru the collection of OverDueItems:

```
foreach(var item in overDueItemsCollection)
{
    ...
}
```

If you are trying to iterate thru properties of OverDueItem:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(overDueItem).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    var value = property.GetValue(overDueItem);
    ...
}
```